# How to persist a View across Activities in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android application and I'd like to maintain a top-bar of sorts in most of my Activities, as per the Twitter and Facebook applications. How is this done? I'd like to keep it there at all times, as it'll provide functionality core to the whole application.

Comment: I am also require the same thing if any one know about this please tell me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Break the title bar out into a separate layout, and use the [include](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) xml tag. I do that in a few of my apps. Each of your activities can inherit from a Base Activity that contains events for the included layout, e.g. if the title bar has buttons.

Example pseudocode below.

title.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView text="Some text"/><Button text="Some Button" onCLick="buttonClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity layouts for each layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <include  layout="@layout/title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
     public void buttonClick(View v) {
          // do something interesting.
     }
}

public class OtherActivity extends BaseActivity {}
```

Comment: this is basically what i do in 1 of my apps

Comment: @robby-pond What would you suggest if one of the activities inherit a ListView? Is there still a way to link to the BaseActivity or you just have to write (and take care to maintain) inside the ListActivity the code for the title buttons?

Comment: @Adinia ListActivity is just a "helper" Activity that wires together some code to make it easier to work with a ListView. You can have a ListView in your layout and not extend ListActivity. You will just have to set the adapter using listView.setAdapter instead of setListAdapter, etc.

Comment: The link in the answer is outdated, so if anyone else happens upon this answer, the new link can be found at: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 2):

I have some issues with the syntax highlight, but tried to provide an example of how to complete similar task:

http://illusionsandroid.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-custom-tab-bar.html

Comment: There are several parts missing, since it already got quite lengthy. i can continue if anyone interested, though syntax highlight problems is a bummer. You can also enhance your project using roboguice

Answer (score 1):

GreenDroid has an excellent toolbar which I've found to be very useful, extensible and easy to implement (and its open source to boot).

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

- the [include](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#include-element) XML element
- [Layout Tricks: Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to define a custom view and re-use it wherever needed.  Though I don't think you'd technically have the same instance across activities, you can produce the illusion by updating it whenever necessary.  (Perhaps in the onResume() method of each activity.)  To save the data you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), which do persist across activities in an application, and even between instances of the particular application.